# Prove that $U$ is $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let's assume we're in the following context:
[image]

where cylinder set is $\left[\omega_1,...,\omega_n \right]=\{ \omega' \in \Omega: \omega'_i=\omega_i \}$.

I want to prove that $U$ is $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ measurable. I cannot use any convergence theorem like the Lebesgue's DCT.

I have no idea where to start. Maybe to prove that this function is continuous, but what distance would I use, and how would I prove it...

Comment: Can you show that $X_n$ is $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}[0,1]$-measurable for each $n$?

Comment: @saz yes, since they are coordinate maps, which are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lebesgue's DCT isn't applicable here since we're not looking at the convergence of integrals.

One way to show the measurability is to metrize the space of $\{0,1\}$ sequences with the following metric $d : \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to [0,\infty)$,
\begin{align*}
d(a,b) = 2^{-n(a,b)}
\end{align*}
where $n(a,b)$ is the first integer $n$ at which the two strings $a$ and $b$ differ. Then you can show that the open sets induced by this metric generate the same $\sigma$ algebra as the one generated by the cylinder sets you mention.

From here it is easy to verify that the mapping you mention from binary expansions to real numbers in $[0,1]$ is continuous with respect to the metric given above (you should also verify that it is a metric). Thus the mapping is measurable.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your help. I also thought about that. But isn't there a problem? for example for point $U(\omega)=1/2$, where $\omega=(1,0,0,...)$. Let's chose an epsilon smaller than 1/2.  Any point to the left of 1/2, will have $\omega=(0,\omega_2,\omega_3,...)$ so $d((1,0,0,...),(0,\omega_2,\omega_3,...)=1/2$ , right?

Comment: Yes this is true. But we need only show the map from binary expansions to real numbers is continuous, not its inverse.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. Show that $X_n$ is $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}([0,1])$-measurable for each $n \geq 1$.
2. By step 1, $$U_k(\omega) := \sum_{n=1}^k X_n(\omega) 2^{-n}$$ is $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}([0,1])$-measurable for all $k \geq 1$, and therefore $$U(\omega) = \lim_{k \to \infty} U_k(\omega)$$ is $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}([0,1])$-measurable.

Comment: Saz, thanks for the help. What theorem are you using for the lim in step 2? I'm not sure I can use it, since I'm following a book in my self-study, and I don't recognize that theorem...

Comment: @Klenke2ed If $f_k$ are $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}$-measurable functions such that $f_k \to f$ pointwise, then $f$ is $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}$-measurable. (This follows e.g. from the fact that $\liminf_{k \to \infty} f_k$ and $\limsup_{k \to \infty} f_k$ are measurable for any sequence of measurable functions $(f_k)_k)$.)

Comment: @Klenke2ed You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll just post an answer with the details from Daniel's answer.

we want $\displaystyle \forall_{y \in \Omega} \forall_{\epsilon>0} \exists_{\delta>0}\forall_{x \in \Omega} x\in B_{\delta}(y)\implies |U(x)-U(y)|<\epsilon$

For $x\neq y$, $x\in B_{\delta}(y)\Leftrightarrow d(x,y)=2^{-k}<\delta$, and

$\displaystyle |U(x)-U(y)|<\sum^{\infty}_{i=k+1}2^{-i}=2^{-k}$, since first $k$ terms of the sum are equal. So if I choose $\delta=\epsilon$, then we have $ x\in B_{\delta}(y)\implies |U(x)-U(y)|<\delta=\epsilon$