# How to determine $\mu \circ U^{-1}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let's assume we're in the following situation:
[image]

where cylinder set is $\left[\omega_1,...,\omega_n \right]=\{ \omega' \in \Omega: \omega'_i=\omega_i \}$.

What's $\mu \circ U^{-1} $ on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]))$?

For this I have honestly no idea how to tackle this... I thought of what would this function look like for a generator of $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$, but not sure how it would look like. I think that $U([\omega_1,...,\omega_n ])=[\sum^n_i\omega_i 2^{-i},\sum^n_i\omega_i 2^{-i}+2^{-n}]$

Also, is there a set $\Omega_0$ to which function $U$ could be restricted to, such that it would be bijective?

For this I think that any $U(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)=U(0,...,0,0,1,1,...,1)$. So I must at least take out either the left hand type sequence, or the right hand type. What I don't know is if I need to take out something more...

Comment: It's a continuation of this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362739/prove-that-u-is-mathcala-mathcalb0-1-measurable

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think about $U$ as taking in a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s and outputting the number in $[0,1]$ with that binary representation.  So, if we choose each bit of a real number uniformly at random, what does that mean about how we chose the number?  To see if there's a smaller set on which $U$ is bijective, think about why it isn't bijective: when does a number have two different binary representations?

Comment: I think we have $U([\omega_1,...,\omega_n])=[\sum^n_{i=1}\omega_i2^{-i},2^{-n}+\sum^n_{i=1}\omega_i2^{-i}]$. But I'm not sure how this helps...
Also I think there's this double representation $U(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)=U(0,...,0,0,1,1,...,1)$. So, if I take out those representations with just one 1, then I should be ok, right?

Comment: @Klenke2ed, Right, the only way to have a double representation is if you have $1$'s repeating at the end.  And note that $U$ isn't defined for finite sequences, it's infinite sequences.

Comment: Marcus, the cylinder set $[\omega_1,...,\omega_n]=\{\omega´ \in \Omega: \omega'_i=\omega_i\}$ is a set of infinite sequences with the first n elements fixed. This part of $\mu \circ U^{-1}$ I have no idea how to solve it... Can you help me a bit more on that part?